# How to fix my password validation rule during confirmation of re-type during sign-up?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I'm using [react-hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com/) and Material-UI for my sign-up form. I'm trying to create a second password field that acts as the validation confirmation to check if the user typed in their correct password in the first field. Following my rule below:

```
                              rules={{

                                        pattern: {
                                            value: field.password2 == field.password,
                                            message: 
                                                <span className={classes.warningText}>
                                                <WarningIcon color="secondary" /> 
                                                    <p style={{ marginLeft: "1vw" }}>
                                                        Invalid use of characters
                                                    </p>
                                                </span>,
                                        }
                                    }}
```

I'm trying to keep it simple and do something like this: value: `field.password2 == field.password`. However `field` is just an imaginary name, how can I reference my first password field in order to replicate the example? They are both using `<TextField>` and are wrapped around a `<Controller>`. I can provide more information about my form but I think this will do below:

```
                            <Grid item xs={12}>
                                <Controller
                                    name="password"
                                    as={
                                    
                                        <TextField
                                            variant="outlined"
                                            required
                                            fullWidth
                                            name="password"
                                            label="Password"
                                            type="password"
                                            id="password"
                                            error={Boolean(fieldsErrors.password)}
                                            onChange={
                                                (evt) =>
                                                {
                                                    let key = evt.currentTarget.name;
                                                    let value = evt.currentTarget.value;
                                                    handleChange({ [key]: value });
                                                }
                                            }
                                            helperText={
                                                <Container component="span">    
                                                    <List disablePadding component="span">
                                                        <ListItem disableGutters={true} ContainerComponent="div">- Password is case-sensitive</ListItem>
                                                        <ListItem disableGutters={true} ContainerComponent="div">- Minimum eight characters</ListItem>
                                                        <ListItem disableGutters={true} ContainerComponent="div">- At least one letter</ListItem>
                                                        <ListItem disableGutters={true} ContainerComponent="div">- At least one number</ListItem>
                                                    </List>
                                                </Container>
                    
                                                }
                                        />
                                    }
                                    control={control}
                                    defaultValue="" 
                                    rules={{
                                        required:
                                            <Container className={classes.warningText}>
                                            <WarningIcon color="secondary" /> 
                                            </Container>,
                                        pattern: {
                                            value: /^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]{8,50}$/,
                                            message: 
                                                <Container className={classes.warningText}>
                                                <WarningIcon color="secondary" /> 
                                                    <span style={{ marginLeft: "1vw" }}>
                                                        Please try another password
                                                    </span>
                                                </Container>,
                                        }
                                    }}
                                />
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item xs={12}>
                                <Controller
                                    name="password2"
                                    as={
                                    
                                        <TextField
                                            variant="outlined"
                                            required
                                            fullWidth
                                            name="password2"
                                            label="Re-type Password"
                                            type="password"
                                            id="password2"
                                            error={Boolean(fieldsErrors.password)}
                                            onChange={
                                                (evt) =>
                                                {
                                                    let key = evt.currentTarget.name;
                                                    let value = evt.currentTarget.value;
                                                    handleChange({ [key]: value });
                                                }
                                            }
                                        />
                                    }
                                    control={control}
                                    defaultValue="" 
                                    rules={{
                                        required:
                                            <span className={classes.warningText}>
                                            <WarningIcon color="secondary" /> 
                                                <p style={{ marginLeft: "1vw" }}>
                                                    Required
                                                </p>
                                            </span>,
                                        pattern: {
                                            value: field.password2 == field.password,
                                            message: 
                                                <span className={classes.warningText}>
                                                <WarningIcon color="secondary" /> 
                                                    <p style={{ marginLeft: "1vw" }}>
                                                        Invalid use of characters
                                                    </p>
                                                </span>,
                                        }
                                    }}
                                />
                                    {fieldsErrors.password?.type && <p>{fieldsErrors.password?.message}</p>}    
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={12}>
```

How can I reference the users input from field `password` and check if its equal to `password2` field and add it to my validation rule?

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In react hook form you can watch both password fields using the `watch` method returned from useForm.

```js
  const { watch, ...etc } = useForm();

  const password = watch("password");
  const password2 = watch("password2");
```

And your validation code can just check `password === password2` somewhere.

See https://react-hook-form.com/api#watch for information on how/when this function runs because your onBlur/onChange strategy may make a difference.

I'll also reference `getValues` as an option if you want to manually set an error in a useEffect. https://react-hook-form.com/api#getValues

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const { password, password2 } = getValues(['password', 'password2'])
  if (password !== password2) setError(...)
  else clearErrors(...)
}, [formState])
```

Answer (score 1):

In React, to validate the values in the form which is constantly changing on "onChange" event it is better to have those in the local component state.
For that, it is advisable to use React Hook "useState".
Here is what you can do:

1: Initialize the state at the beginning of the component:

```
const [formFields, setFormFields] = React.useState({
    password: '',
    retypePassword: ''
})
```

2: Handle the "onChange" event this way:

```
const handlePasswordChange = (event) => {
    setFormFields({ ...formFields, password: event.target.value})
}
```

and for retype password

```
const handleRetypePasswordChange = (event) => {
    setFormFields({ ...formFields, retypePassword: event.target.value })
}
```

or pass an argument to specify the field and dynamically change the value

3: Now you can validate for the equivalency this way:

```
formFields.password === formFields.retypePassword
```

Also, feel free to checkout the popular library that can handle the advanced validations for you:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup

Comment: This functionality is provided by the library the OP mentions (react hook form).